# liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-00984: column not allowed here [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE account MODIFY

Tags: java, oracle, sequence, liquibase, changeset

I used liquibase and oracle database for my java spring boot code.
But I have a big problem because I made a mistake!!!
I created tables and in id unique column I set a not right value, and I use hibernate_sequence for all my tables.
So I had many tables and sequence for ids are very bad huge number after short time.
But I don't know how can I change default value of id's in Liquibase, I want change default value next val in id, by another sequence, not hibernate_sequence.  my code is here:

My code is as below:

```
<changeSet id="1000" author="jhipster">
   <createSequence sequenceName="hibernate_sequence" startValu="1000" incrementBy="50"/>
    <createTable tableName="jhi_user">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
</changeSet>
```

Then I want change the next default value of "id" by another sequence then I created new sequence with name "sequence_account" and wanted to change default value of "id" by this sequence ,

My code is as below:

```
<changeSet id="tstAmir" author="amir">
   <addDefaultValue tableName="account" columnName="accountid" defaultValueSequenceNext="sequence_account"/>
</changeSet>
```

Then it returns an exception:

```
 Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
[Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE account MODIFY accountid DEFAULT sequence_account.nextval]

liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/changelog_account.xml::tstAmir::amir:
 Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-00984: column not allowed here Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE TEST_HOST.account MODIFY accountid DEFAULT TEST_HOST.sequence_account.nextval]   at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:619)
            at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
            at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79)
```

---

How can I change it's next default value in oracle?

Comment: Which version of the Oracle database are you using?

Comment: hi @LukeWoodward i use 12c and also 11g versions in two area